# How can I make the PyDev editor selectively ignore errors?

Tags: python, pydev, jython, python-import

I'm using PyDev under Eclipse to write some Jython code.  I've got numerous instances where I need to do something like this:

```
import com.work.project.component.client.Interface.ISubInterface as ISubInterface
```

The problem is that PyDev will always flag this as an error and say "Unresolved import: ISubInterface".  The code works just fine, it's just that I'd rather not have these little white/red X-marks next to my code and have my Problems tab littered with these errors.

Is there a way I can add a magic comment or something like that to the end of the line to make PyDev ignore the false error, similar to how you can sprinkle comments like "# pylint: disable-msg=E1101" to make PyLint ignore errors?

Also, there's a possibility I'm just doing it wrong when it comes to using Java interfaces in Jython.  In which case a little bit of guidance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can make Pylint ignore errors but the error is from Pydev here and I don't know how to suppress this.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can add a comment

```
#@UnresolvedImport
#@UnusedVariable
```

So your import becomes:

```
import com.work.project.component.client.Interface.ISubInterface as ISubInterface #@UnresolvedImport
```

That should remove the error/warning. There are other comments you can add as well.

Answer (score 30):

Add the hash character # at the end of the line then with the cursor on the flagged error, press Ctrl-1.  One of the options in the menu will be something like `@UndefinedVariable`.  Adding this comment will cause PyDev to ignore the error.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, at least in Eclipse Juno, latest PyDev.  Autofix shows the option for `@UndefinedVariable`, but choosing it has no effect.

Comment: (little thing: Cmd-1 on Mac; and you need to have the # already added otherwise the @UndefinedVariable will appear as an option but never add)

Comment: Works for me! Thank God! Got rid of those annoying "broken package" icons when things like win-curses or Celery added variables at runtime

Comment: This was very useful. It was frustrating to see red X errors where I know there is not a problem as the code works fine. I have not been able to fine a site that list all the available `#@` options. Do you have a link for the list of options?

Comment: Thanks for explaining the ctrl-1 feature.  Very useful.

Answer (score 6):

You can make the ignore like the other posts suggest, but the real problem is that Pydev cannot find that class... If you add a .jar that contains that class to your PYTHONPATH it should be able to resolve it (or if you have a Java project that has that class, you should be able to mark that project as a Pydev project and add its bin folder to the project PYTHONPATH -- in which case that class should be found too).

Answer (score -1):

It is not a PYTHONPATH issue.  It is related to importing/using static class-internal members of a Java class.  I am getting the same sort of thing all over the place e.g. when trying to use constants in java.awt.Color:

```
import java.awt.Color as Color
borderColor = Color.BLACK # get "Undefined variable from import: BLACK" error
```

There is no way I've found to import Color.BLACK in this case.  Thanks to iceman for at least pointing out the #@UndefinedVariable flag.  That helps a lot.  Note also that this is NOT a jython problem, the code runs just fine.  It's just an issue with PyDev.

Comment: That was stated as much in the original question: "The problem is that PyDev will always flag this as an error and say "Unresolved import: ISubInterface". The code works just fine"