# Pydev shows unresolved import, but script runs?

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

I am using PyDev.

I am trying to organise my project classes into packages.

e.g.  In a folder I have a module at /libraries/fund_price_library.py

In another file in my project, I try to import using:

```
from libraries.fund_price_library import FundPriceLibrary as fpl
```

PyDev underlines "FundPriceLibrary as fpl" in red, marking it with this error:

```
unresolved import fpl
```

However, my script works perfectly fine, so I believe that I am doing the import correctly.

I have lots of similar errors all over my project, and it looks messy.  However, my python code works, so I assume I am importing correctly.

How do I suppress these errors?

Answer (score 13):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631377/unresolved-import-issues-with-pydev-and-eclipse) might hold the solution to your problem.

> In the properties for your pydev project, there's a pane called "PyDev - PYTHONPATH", with a sub-pane called "External Libraries". You can add source folders (any folder that has an **init**.py) to the path using that pane. Your project code will then be able to import modules from those source folders.

It might just be that PyDev doesn't know where to find the files.

Comment: Strangely, it works, though my files are in my current project, rather than in an external library.

Comment: I would guess something about the path in PyDev settings is screwy - so PyDev can't find the library, even though Python can. (also you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark)

Comment: python 3 has implicit namespaces packages and init files are not mandatory. I don't know if it's related but my project does not contain init files and unfortunately this did not fix the problem for me. See my answer though.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. Solution is (I have Eclipse 4.6 w/ Pydev 5.6):

```
Project > Properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH > tab Source Folders
```

Do this: `Add source folder` (button) and add your (current) source dir, in my case it was `src` subdir so new item apears in the window : 
`/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/src`

So now I have this there:

```
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}
/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/src
```

and my PyDev is happy now :)

Comment: Even though there are many fancier and more thorough solutions listed on this and other similar questions: this simple solution is the one that worked for me.

Comment: This worked. I found I had to restart Eclipse for it to take effect

Comment: @S.N. File > Restart Does the thing!

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 has [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/) so `__init__.py` files in sub packages are not mandatory. However, it seems PyDev still needs them.

My solution was to add empty `__init__.py` files in subpackages.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem in a new project, with "unresolved import" errors an imported symbol is not actually in use yet.
It turned out to be a problem only when the eclipse "project" name and an underlying python "package" name are identical. When I changed the eclipse project name to something else, the error messages went away (seems like there might be a bug somewhere).

BTW: using Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0), with PyDev version 7.1.0.201902031515

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution:

Perhaps you can tell pydev to ignore the import error by using the markup UnresolvedImport in your code.
See [how-can-i-make-the-pydev-editor-selectively-ignore-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702043/how-can-i-make-the-pydev-editor-selectively-ignore-errors) for a discussion on the topic.

PS If you're using pydev in eclipse, ctrl+1 should suggest this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried to set PYTHONPATH on PyDev but that did not help for me. However, what did work was setting folder to "Forced Builtins"

my project folder structure looks like this

```
root_project
├── src
│   ├── code_here.py
│   ├── some_dependency_folder_here
│   │   └── models
│   │       │   ├── some_class_here.py
```

inside code_here.py

```
from src.some_dependency_folder_here.models.some_class_here import SomeClass
```

To add **src** do the following: Eclipse -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter -> Forced Builtins -> new -> add *src* . Fixed the issue (make sure to close and open the file)

Now everything properly gets resolved

[image: eclipse PyDev settings]